# How to use CONCAT in codeigniter datatable query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datatables, concatenation

I am using codeigniter framework, in this I was using datatable to generate values to view files. I need to CONCAT option to this query's. But when I use it shows 500 internal server errors. Below I have given the query.

```
 $this->load->library('datatables');

 $this->datatables
    ->select("sales.id as sid, CONCAT(sales.id, ' ',sales.export_status) as chid, date, reference_no, customer_name, note, delete_status, table_name, count, inv_total, inv_discount, total_tax2, total, internal_note");
 $this->datatables->join('order_table', 'order_table.id=sales.tableid', 'left');
 $this->datatables->from('sales');
```

I don't know what is the issue, I refereed so many links, but I cant get correct solution. Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 internal server error would be from your script due to redirection

Comment: But when i remove the CONCAT option in query means it is working fine.

Comment: Add `, FALSE);` at last in your query and try

Comment: i have export_status in sales. The chid i added for alias.

Comment: ya correct , but i dont have chid in order_table.

Comment: @saty i have added FALSE in last of the select option. So now it is working. Thank you.

Comment: You'r wellcome @JaganAkash

Comment: ya sure, you can add it in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

```
  $this->datatables->select("sales.id as sid, CONCAT(sales.id, ' ',sales.export_status) as chid, date, reference_no, customer_name, note, delete_status, table_name, count, inv_total, inv_discount, total_tax2, total, internal_note",FALSE);
```

Comment: Edit $this->datatables->select(); Missing select spelling.